# Threading error with log4net inside method running in hangfire

Tags: c#, multithreading, log4net, hangfire

I running process with hangfire, recurring task.  These tasks are set to kick off every minute and processing thousands of rows from the DB.

I had them running in my test environment smoothly till I added log4net logging inside those methods.  Now log4net throws a threading error.

```
log4net:ERROR Failed to append to appender [AdoNetAppender]
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
   at System.Threading.Monitor.ReliableEnter(Object obj, Boolean& lockTaken)
   at System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(Object obj, Boolean& lockTaken)
   at log4net.Appender.AppenderSkeleton.DoAppend(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
   at log4net.Util.AppenderAttachedImpl.AppendLoopOnAppenders(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
log4net:ERROR Exception while logging
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
   at log4net.Util.AppenderAttachedImpl.AppendLoopOnAppenders(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
   at log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger.CallAppenders(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
   at log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger.ForcedLog(Type callerStackBoundaryDeclaringType, Level level, Object message, Exception exception)
   at log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger.Log(Type callerStackBoundaryDeclaringType, Level level, Object message, Exception exception)
log4net:ERROR Failed to append to appender [AdoNetAppender]
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
   at System.Threading.Monitor.ReliableEnter(Object obj, Boolean& lockTaken)
   at System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(Object obj, Boolean& lockTaken)
   at log4net.Appender.AppenderSkeleton.DoAppend(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
   at log4net.Util.AppenderAttachedImpl.AppendLoopOnAppenders(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
log4net:ERROR Exception while logging
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
   at log4net.Util.AppenderAttachedImpl.AppendLoopOnAppenders(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
   at log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger.CallAppenders(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
   at log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger.ForcedLog(Type callerStackBoundaryDeclaringType, Level level, Object message, Exception exception)
   at log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger.Log(Type callerStackBoundaryDeclaringType, Level level, Object message, Exception exception)
```

not exactly sure how to fix this?

I have read that for background threads you can set IsBackground=true and will destroy the worker, but that to me seems like it would be in the hangfire subsystem to manage.

Im more concerned of fixing it from a log4net or writing the method differently.  On that note, This is test project, but in the real environment i will not be calling log4net directly, it will be wrapped in LoggingService.  For this test I am just trying to keep it simple.  unless i have no choice.

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out working out something else.  so initially, the Hangfire tables and log tables were in the same database along with tables from the system.  I noticed in testing a few times i would hit a connection string pooling error.  I wasnt really worried about this from test code cause it simplied version of the architecture that will be inplace.  Anyway my test are meant to hammer the DB to simulate the millions of transactions.  In this testing I realized to alleviate some of that hammering i should move hangfire to its on DB, which will save on the connectionstrings and also move some of that db work, while doing that I might as well move the logging to its DB also, which again will save connectionstring in the pool.

I say i stumbled on this because i wasnt thinking about logging when i decided to do this.  so when i ran my test code again i decided to uncomment my direct logging in the methods hangfire executes and it worked the way i originally intended when i asked the question.

Long story short, remember that connection strings run on different threads, separating DB's gives a hidden thread advantage.  This is a very simeple test application not code i would run in production, not none the less i could of run into the same issue there too.  Will find out soon enough as the real arch development is almost ready for testing.